# SMTP Sendmail With PEAR not using formating from database

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am using PEAR to send an email with smtp authentication.

Currently i store the email with formatting in a database and then send it out from there. The email is sending perfectly. But the email body is not being formatted. instead it is taking whatever is in the database and using it directly as plain text not HTML formatted text.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

```
function sendmail($from,$to,$subject,$body,$host,$username,$password){
      $headers = array ('From' => $from,   'To' => $to,   'Subject' => $subject);
      $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',   array ('host' => $host,     'auth' => true,     'username' => $username,     'password' => $password));
      $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
      if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
          echo "<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>";  
      } else {   
        echo "<p>Message successfully sent!</p>";  
      }
    }
```

right now `$body` = `<p>&nbsp;Lets make this an epic test mail. and see what happens?</p>` so it should remove the tags and just place it in a email.

But instead i get the email with the text being `<p>&nbsp;Lets make this an epic test mail. and see what happens?</p>`

Comment: add to headers `'Content-type' => 'text/html;charset=iso-8859-1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want HTML email then you need to add the header:

```
 'Content-type' => 'text/html;charset=iso-8859-1'
```

your charset may vary